# Chief Factors of a Group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally soluble, locally finite group.
Has $G$ a chief factor?
Has $G$ a $p$-chief factor for a fixed prime $p$?

**Chief Series**
A chief series is a maximal normal series for a group.

**Chief Factor**
A factor of a chief series.

**$p$-chief Factor**
A chief factor that is a $p$-group.

Comment: Doesn't locally finite trivially imply locally graded?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry :D

Comment: What does chief factor mean? What does $p$-chief factor mean?

Comment: A factor of a chief series. A chief factor that is a p-group. In any periodic locally soluble group a chief factor is a $p$-group.

Comment: Then obviously this is possible: take $G$ to be $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ say.

Comment: Maybe in a particular case... I want to know if this holds in general...

Comment: So you don't actually mean that "is there any chance", then?

Comment: Well, any *finite* soluble group answers your first question positively, but even here $p$-chief factors may not exist, as $\,S_4\,$ shows (with $\,p\,$ dividing the group's order, to avoid trivialities)

Comment: @DonAntonio: If I understand the terminology correctly, $S_4$ has chief factors $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$, $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$, and $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$. That covers all the primes dividing the order.

Comment: Of what *normal* series of $\,S_4\,$ is $\,C_3\,$ a chief factor, @ChrisEagle ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, of $\{1\} < V < A_4 < S_4$, where $V$ is the Klein 4-group in $A_4$.

Comment: Of course, the *only* one non-trivial normal series of $\,S_4\,$...! I really must go to eat something now.

Comment: @DonAntonio, is either lack of food or lack of sleep. For me it's the second one, usually ;-)

Comment: Me too, though most of the time it actually is lack of active neurons but I don't like that much to accept this last option, so I better convince myself is lack of food or whatever.